# Create a grouped bar chart from a list of lists in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

When I pass a simple list to ax.bar(), it plots it just fine.  But I have a several lists within a list.  This is greatly simplified, but something like:

```
data = [[5,10], [7,11], [3,9]]
```

What I would like to do is plot a grouped bar graph so that at 0 on the x-axis I have two vertical bars, one going to 5, the other to 10. At x=1 I'd have two bars going to 7 and 11, x=2 has two bars going to 3 and 9.

My question is, is there any simple way to pass in just `data`?  Or do I need to extract out two new lists from the master and then plot those as follows:

```
data_a = [5,7,3]
data_b = [10,11,9]

ax.bar(3, data_a, tick_label=range(3))
ax.bar(3, data_b, tick_label=range(3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in function for that. If you are open to other packages, you can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Or you need to draw them separately as you pointed out.